# QuickBlox video did not get video strem

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, quickblox

I need to join the video call on click of JOIN NOW, for that I have created a user after login and create a session for the user and call function receivedRemoteVideoTrack but not getting video stream. Can you please guys help me out for that what step I need to follow and If I have made some mistake. Below is my code for the login user and create the session.  Thank you in Advance

```
 let qbid2 = "492479" //qb_username
    let qbpass = "4hw148#ijeey@q4h3t4kjx" //qb_password

    QBRequest.logIn(withUserLogin: qbid2, password: qbpass, successBlock: { response, user in

        let currentUser = user

        currentUser.id = user.id // your current user's ID
        currentUser.password = user.password
        // your current user's password

        QBChat.instance.connect(withUserID: currentUser.id,
                                password:currentUser.password!,
                                completion: { [weak self] error in
                                    if let error = error {
                                    }
            }
        )
    }, errorBlock: { response in

        if let error1 = response.error {
            print("error: \(error1)")
            print("response",response)

        }
    })

//creating session
let opponentsIDs = [102138609]

let session = QBRTCClient.instance().createNewSession(withOpponents: opponentsIDs as [NSNumber], with: conferenceType) 
  // receivedRemoteVideoTrack
 func session(session: QBRTCSession!, receivedRemoteVideoTrack videoTrack: QBRTCVideoTrack!, fromUser userID: NSNumber!) {
        //self.opponentVideoView?.setVideoTrack(videoTrack)

        print(videoTrack)
    }
```

[image: Below is the screen to JOIN The CAll or NOT]

Comment: better ask quickblox support team. coz here most of us will have to go through the complete documentation and process of quickblox to understand how it works, which we won't.

Comment: Agreeing with above comment, please contact [QuickBlox support](https://assist.quickblox.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit) for resolution and provide reproducing steps along with client-side logs.